# I want a read more/hide button when there's multiple lines

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

I'm creating a comment section (something similar to youtube), and i want be able to show readmore/hide button when the {{content}} has multiple lines.
This is what I've done so far, my read more/hide button works since I added a computed lineclamp, to make the content show two lines only when there's mutltiple lines, I only want to show the button in case there's multiples lines.
But if you have any other suggestions to make it work, I'm open for it.

`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{ author }}</h4>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted ml-3">
                {{ timeAgo(createdAt) }} ago
            </h6>
        </div>
        <p class="multiline" :style="{ '-webkit-line-clamp': computedLineclamp }"><b class="timestamp" v-if="timestamp !== null">@{{
        timeToHHMMSS(timestamp)
}}</b> {{ content }}
        </p>
        <div>
            <base-button v-show="!readmore" @click="changeLineclamp()" link class="text-white p-0" size="sm">Read
                more</base-button>
            <base-button v-show="readmore" @click="hideContent()" link class="text-white p-0"
                size="sm">Hide</base-button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
  
<script>
// Internal modules
import { timeSince, toHHMMSS } from "@/plugins/timeControls.js";

export default {
    name: "comment-item",
    data() {
        return {
            lineclamp: 2,
            readmore: false,
            showButton: true,
        }
    },
    props: {
        id: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        author: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
        timestamp: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
        content: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changeLineclamp() {
            this.lineclamp = 'initial';
            this.readmore = true;
            this.showButton = false;
        },
        hideContent() {
            this.lineclamp = 2;
            this.readmore = false
        },
        timeAgo(date) {
            return timeSince(date);
        },
        timeToHHMMSS(time) {
            return toHHMMSS(time);
        },
    },
    computed: {
        computedLineclamp() {
            return this.lineclamp;
        },
    },
};
</script>
  
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/assets/sass/dashboard/custom/_variables.scss";

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.button {
    visibility: none;
}

.timestamp {
    color: $primary;
}

.multiline {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

    &.__lineclamp {
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    }

    &.__none {
        -webkit-line-clamp: initial;
    }
}
</style>
```

`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnthz.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMP8N.png)

As I said it does work here, but the readmore/hide button shows up in all the comment section, I tried to use the height function to make it work, but i doesn't

`

```
 <div v-if="content.height() > 2">
            <base-button v-show="!readmore" @click="changeLineclamp()" link class="text-white p-0" size="sm">Read
                more</base-button>
            <base-button v-show="readmore" @click="hideContent()" link class="text-white p-0"
                size="sm">Hide</base-button>
        </div>
```

`

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive **summary of your problem as the title of your question**."_

Comment: I think you already have asked the same question here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74890847/show-read-only-hide-button-only-when-the-content-is-over-two-lines?noredirect=1#comment132315653_74890847